# Ask to change layout of the GridView on ASP.NET by C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Sorry for the stupid question but I really need to ask the way to handle this task. I have research many solved question in here but I can apply it to my task. Maybe I am not good enough to understand it. Please give me the suggestions.

My project is written by C#. They used the GridView to show the data from the database. BUT now, my customer want to use GridView and to create a same showed table like the old one, but it's in the different way.

My current showed table is like:

```
   No. |  Name  |     DOB    | Status | ...
    1  | Name A | 01/01/2014 |  Onl   | ...
    2  | Name B | 01/01/2014 |  Off   | ...
    3  | Name C | 01/01/2014 |  Off   | ...
    4  | Name D | 01/01/2014 |  Onl   | ...
```

Now, I want to change it that way:

```
    No.   | 1
    Name  | Name A
    DOB   | 01/01/2014
    Status| Onl
---------------------------------
    No.   | 2
    Name  | Name B
    DOB   | 01/01/2014
    Status| Onl
---------------------------------
    No.   | 3
    Name  | Name C
    DOB   | 01/01/2014
    Status| Onl
---------------------------------
    No.   | 4
    Name  | Name D
    DOB   | 01/01/2014
    Status| Onl
---------------------------------
```

**IMPORTANT: Just only use GRIDVIEW.**

Have somebody to help me handling this task. I am not good in ASP.NET. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why the artificial requirement to only use GridView and not something like DetailsView or Repeater?

Comment: I don't know. They said that they don't want to change old source code, they just think that is easy when changing the layout look like HTML and CSS. I have told them about this but they said that can be handle by gridview.
I am not good in ASP.NET so I don't know much about this. Please help.

Comment: That would not be something easy to accomplish with GridView, but it'd be trivially simple with DetailsView or Repeater. Put your big boy pants on and tell them that in your experience, GridView is NOT the correct approach to use in this situation. You'll have to change the source code either way, might as well use the correct approach instead of trying to hack something together.

Comment: Just use two template column and inject whatever you want.  Let me know if you need code snippet for that.

Comment: mason: if I use DetailsView like your suggestion. what should I do? Tools or Coding. Can you give me the code example.

@Abhi: I can image your way. Can you type some code example, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If current code is like below.**

```
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="No." HeaderText="No." />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DOB" HeaderText="DOB" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" />
    </Columns>
```

**You can change it like below.**

```
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Key">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server">No.</asp:Label><br />
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server">Name</asp:Label><br />
                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server">DOB</asp:Label><br />
                <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server">Status</asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="Value">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server"><%# Eval("No.") %></asp:Label><br />
                <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server"><%# Eval("Name") %></asp:Label><br />
                <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server"><%# Eval("DOB") %></asp:Label><br />
                <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server"><%# Eval("Status") %></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
```

Comment: I have changed the layout of the table. I checked the source code and it's not call the varible from datasource. They coded the class to bound the data. Now, I don't know how to set data to the column with new layout. hix hix

Comment: How can I show the source code in there. It will mixed together on this comment field.

Comment: I checed updated post. It only 'Number of order number' and 'Question content' are bound from code behind. So you can almost change layout like above. To know how are they bound, check `RowDataBound` event in code behind.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7gh1X_dl0QLaUkzbVBJN1JWZW8/edit?usp=sharing

This file is codebehind of the  OnRowDataBound="GridView_history_RowDataBound". Hope this help full.

Comment: At first, you should change layout like above and figure out what problem is there.

Comment: Oh thanks, but I think this idea can't be come true. I figured out when I change the layout, it took many rows. On one screen with the original, I can view at least 10 rows of data. So now, I just see 4-5 rows. It's too uncomfortable for the user. I rejeced this task. Fortunately, my manager understood the problem and he agreed to reject. Thank a lot for your warmly helpings.